# Creating Multi-dimensional array from data in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have table named 'vehicles' in CodeIgniter project.

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | name    | make   |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 | Corolla | Toyota |
|  2 | Parado  | Toyota |
|  3 | Sunny   | Nissan |
|  4 | Maxima  | Nissan |
|  5 | Premoio | Toyota |
+----+---------+--------+
```

How can I get multi-dimensional array out of that as shown below:

```
Array
(
    [Toyota] => Array
        (
            [1] => Corolla
            [2] => Parado
            [5] => Premio
        )

    [Nissan] => Array
        (
            [3] => Sunny
            [4] => Maxima
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that you can get all records from table in a array as in `$rows` variable.

```
$rows = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Corolla', 'make' => 'Toyota'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Parado', 'make' => 'Toyota'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Sunny', 'make' => 'Nissan'],
    ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Maxima', 'make' => 'Nissan'],
    ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'Premoio', 'make' => 'Toyota']
];

$result = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $result[$row['make']][$row['id']] = $row['name'];
}
```

And just in a single loop you can achieve that. I hope it will help.

**CodeIgniter 3.x**

```
$query = $this->db->get('vehicles');

$result = [];
if($this->db->count_all_results() > 0)
{
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $result[$row['make']][$row['id']] = $row['name'];
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$cars = array();

$unique_makes = $this->db->distinct('make')->get('vehicles')->result();

foreach($unique_makes as $make){
    $models = $this->db->where('make', $make)->get('vehicles')->result();
    $cars[$make] = $models;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieve the result with following code. Jeremy Jackson answer gave me idea what should I do to achieve that. But his code didn't work. Thank you Jeremy anyway.

Here is my code:

```
$cars = array();

$makes = $this->db->select('make')->distinct()->get('vehicles')->result_array();
$makes = array_column($makes, 'make');

foreach($makes as $make) {
    $models = $this->db->where('make', $make)->get('vehicles')->result_array();
    $cars[$make] = array_combine(array_column($models, 'id'), array_column($models, 'name'));
}

print_r($cars);
```

Comment: You are doing more than one mysql query in your code where you can do it with a single query. Isn't that? Did you saw my answer?

Comment: @HADI sorry I couldn't understand your code first. Now I see this. You showed me the right way.